# Why Intl.NumberFormat formats 1000000000 bytes as 1BB instead of 1GB?

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

I am trying to configure my `Intl.NumberFormat` instance to show a proper unit for large amounts but seems like it shows `B` instead of `G` for 1000000000, e.g. 1BB/s instead of 1GB/s.

Here is my instance:

```js
const rateFormatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
    style: 'unit',
    unit: 'byte-per-second',
    unitDisplay: 'narrow',
    notation: 'compact',
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  })
  
 console.log(rateFormatter.format("1000000000"));
```

Why is it so? My browser is the latest Chrome on MacOS.

Comment: same issue on windows chrome latest version

Comment: Also in latest Firefox on Windows

Comment: This is related to this question https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/730

Comment: Good find @Akxe

Comment: It's because you have 1 billion (B) of byte-per-second (B/s). Together that's BB/s. It's not meant to use SI prefixes (even the "K" is upper case which is wrong if it were SI). It has M, B, T for million, billion, trillion.

Comment: @CherryDT if that was true, then why isn't `1000` formatted as "TB/s" for "thousands"? It formats as KB/s instead. And `1000000000000` formats as "TB/s" which might be "trillion" but still the K is inconsistent.

Comment: Because that's just how people commonly use the prefix. Think of money, people write $5K, $5M, $5B, $5T. It probably wasn't designed be immediately attached to a unit, in fact the issue linked by Akxe even states that there should be a space after the first B which is currently missing (of course it's unfortunate that this looks almost right and may be used in practice as a way to format "kilo" and "mega" as actual unit prefix)

Comment: I would replace `BB` with `GB` and call it done...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a workaround which checks the size of the number and picks an appropriate unit.

```js
const bandwidth = (bytespersec) => {
   let units = "byte-per-second";
   let divisor = 1;
   if (bytespersec >= 1e9) {
     units = "gigabyte-per-second";
     divisor = 1e9;
   } else if (bytespersec >= 1e6) {
     units = "megabyte-per-second";
     divisor = 1e6;
   } else if (bytespersec >= 1e3) {
     units = "kilobyte-per-second";
     divisor = 1e3;
   }
   // etc, add more if needed.  Be sure to put the largest unit first in the above if (or re-do the logic)
   
   let f = Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
      style: 'unit',
      unit: units,
      unitDisplay: 'short',
      notation: 'compact',
      maximumFractionDigits: 2,
   });
   
   return f.format(bytespersec / divisor);
 };
 
 console.log(bandwidth(1));
 console.log(bandwidth(1025));
 console.log(bandwidth(1234567));
 console.log(bandwidth(234567890));
 console.log(bandwidth(2000000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with `Intl` itself.

as your code in your question produces `1BB/s`

if you change the `unitDisplay` to be `long` instead, you will get `"1B bytes per second"` in the console, like

```js
const rateFormatter = Intl.NumberFormat('en', {
    style: 'unit',
    unit: 'byte-per-second',
    unitDisplay: 'long',
    notation: 'compact',
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
  })
  
 console.log(rateFormatter.format("1000000000"));
```

meaning that the the issue is with the `format` function

## Test 1

after some testing.

I've discovered that.

passing value of

`1000000000` the output is `"1B bytes per second"` (which you originaly passing in as per your question)

`100000000` the output is `"100M bytes per second"`

if we change the `unitDisplay` back to `narrow`

## Test 2

and if we run the same test again, we get

passing value of

`1000000000` the output is `"1BB/s"` (which you originaly passing in as per your question)

`100000000` the output is `"100MB/s"`

## Solution

the issue is that the `B` refers to `billion` so the output is correct but it does not give `billion bytes per second` in the long unit display setting, so its not broken but rather, just badly implemented, with values so large it simple just uses 1B meaning 1 billion

Comment: "*there is a max int limit which breaks the formater*" not exactly , since `1000000000000` is formatted as "TB/s". It's just the "giga" that is somehow shortened to "B".

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, it just breaks, this is a known bug see -> [bug tracker](https://github.com/tc39/ecma402/issues/730)